# How can I implement a layer which can keep several decimal?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to achieve, in the output layer to retain two decimal functions. Because I want to use it between two convolution layers, so I want to use it to achieve this.

But because the two decimals it keeps often overflow, I don't know how to solve it?

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.Variable([3.5115155, 3.365, 3.38115155, 3.81151536, 3.38115159, 3.38115158, 3.398115155], dtype=tf.float32)

@tf.custom_gradient
def round_test(x):
   def grad(dy):
     return 1.0*dy
   return tf.math.round(x * 100)/100, grad

output_clip = round_test(input)

grad_clip = tf.gradients(output_clip, input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   print("input:", sess.run(input))
   print("output_clipping:", sess.run(output_clip))
   print("with clipping:", sess.run(grad_clip)[0])
```

This is a mistake.
input: [3.5115156 3.365 3.3811514]
output_clipping: [3.51 3.36 3.3799999]

I expect the output of `roud_test(3.3811514)` to be `3.38`, but the actual output is `3.3799999`
I just want to keep two decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tf.py_func`:

```
import numpy as np #add

return tf.py_func(lambda a:np.round(a,2),[x],tf.float32),grad
```

The results:

```
input: [3.5115156 3.365     3.3811514]
output_clipping: [3.51 3.36 3.38]
with clipping: [1. 1. 1.]
```